# How to hook up Google Maps to GeoDjango?

Tags: django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geodjango

GeoDjango docs don't tell anything about hooking up GMap and I don't understand what's going on.

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    coords = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.gis import forms
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['coords', 'name']
```

In the add_location.html such code was automatically generated for 'coords':

```
<div id="div_id_coords" class="form-group">
    <div class="controls ">
        <div id="id_coords_div_map">

            <div id="id_coords_map"></div>

            <span class="clear_features">
                <a href="javascript:geodjango_coords.clearFeatures()">Delete</a>
            </span>
            <textarea id="id_coords" class="vSerializedField required" cols="150" rows="10" name="coords"></textarea>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                    var map_options = {};
                    var options = {
                        geom_name: 'Point',
                        id: 'id_coords',
                        map_id: 'id_coords_map',
                        map_options: map_options,
                        map_srid: 4326,
                        name: 'coords'
                    };

                    var geodjango_coords = new MapWidget(options);
            </script>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my js file I am trying to get coordinates of marker into my model:

```
    var mapOptions = {...};
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#id_coords_map')[0], mapOptions);

    map.addListener('click', function(e){
            placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
            var position = marker.getPosition();
    });

    var marker;
    function placeMarker(latLng, map) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
        return marker
    }
```

But it doesn't work. It even doesn't come to getting coordinates because I get the error in the chrome console (when I push button Add location at my form):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MapWidget is not defined
```

related to the line:

```
var geodjango_coords = new MapWidget(options);
```

And as validation error at the form field COORDS I can see - "No geometry value provided"

I guessed that something is wrong with connecting GMap and checked what widget was in COORDS field (via `self.fields['coords'].widget` in the `__init__` of ModelForm) and it turned out that it was OpenLayers widget.

What should I do to get GMap as widget and get marker's coords saved in the instance?

P.S. HEAD content at the page (it is about connecting to google maps):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/5/intl/ru_ALL/common.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/5/intl/ru_ALL/map.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/5/intl/ru_ALL/util.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/5/intl/ru_ALL/onion.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/5/intl/ru_ALL/stats.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/5/intl/ru_ALL/controls.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/5/intl/ru_ALL/marker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just to validate: you're 100% sure your own JS file is loaded *after* the Google JS files? It seems like MapWidget is not a Google Maps thing though, if I check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ :)

Comment: I included google script in the HEAD, while jquery script at the bottom of BODY. I'd like to notice that I can see Google Map in the COORDS field.. but it is not widget. Because OpenLayers widget is sort of staying under Google map.

Comment: And possibly that is why I get validation error "No geometry value provided"... because I click at GMap, but the form expects the value from OpenLayers widget... it is my suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hook up GMap to GeoDjango?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906374/how-to-hook-up-gmap-to-geodjango)

Comment: yes..it is duplicate but I did not get the answer and desided to do new post with some differences.. I just do not know how to delete posts..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding {{ form.media }} into HEAD has taken away the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: MapWidget is not defined' from the Chrome console.. but it didn't solve the problem - please, look at - 
[GeoDjango Google Maps - error - No geometry value provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330367/geodjango-google-maps-error-no-geometry-value-provided)